# androidx.security dependency issue

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-jetpack

I needed to encrypt my SharedPreferences so I decided to try and use:

`implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc01'`

It requires a minimum Sdk of 23 so I changed my app to be compatible wih it.

Now im getting a bunch of red lines that look as follows:

```
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Timestamp$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Timestamp$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TimestampOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TimestampProto found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Type found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Type$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Type$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TypeOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TypeProto found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt32Value found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt32Value$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt32Value$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt32ValueOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt64Value found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt64Value$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt64Value$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UInt64ValueOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSetLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$2 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$Processor found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$SafeProcessor found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$UnpairedSurrogateException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$UnsafeProcessor found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Value found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Value$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Value$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Value$KindCase found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ValueOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$2 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$3 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$4 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$JavaType found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$2 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$3 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WrappersProto found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.1) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

My build.gradle looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This depends on `com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.3.0`,which pulls in `protobuf-javalite`:

```
implementation ("androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc01") {
    exclude group: "com.google.protobuf", module: "protobuf-javalite"
}
```

Comment: This worked mate thank you. Is there anything I should be aware of that it can affect other things in my app?

Comment: @Ben while there is still one occurrence of `protobuf-javalite` left in the package, it should work as excepted, because the dependencies share these among each other.

Comment: It solved the previous but gives this one: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerDefaultInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite;)V in class Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite' not sure if connected

Comment: @Ben Without the `build.gradle` there won't be any better answer, since this is anything but reproducible. Un-accepting the proper answer won't improve the inaccurate question.

Answer (score 2):

> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf

You can add below in your ***MODULE*** level `build.gradle` section.

```
android {

  configurations {
        implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'
        implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-java'
        }

}
```

Comment: Either I added it in the wrong place or it didnt work.  I added it right under dependencies {}

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue declared in issue tracker :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154434594

Please use last version available :

```
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc03"
```